# How To Delete File From RTC Changeset Using CLI

Tags: version-control, rtc, jazz

I'm using the RTC 3.0.1 CLI (lscm) and I have a file checked into a changeset that I would like to delete.  There doesn't appear to be a straightforward way to do this, any idea?

Answer (score 5):

I hate answering my own question, but I figured it out.  Perhaps this will help others.

RTC really makes you think about source control in a different way than SVN, or even git.  In order to delete a file from an RTC changeset, you just remove the file locally and checkin the directory.

```
$ rm myfile
$ cd .. 
$ lscm checkin mydir
```

Undoing changes with the 'undo' command

```
$ lscm undo myfile
```

Here is a rosetta stone of sorts for the RTC CLI that clued me in:
[Git v Subversion v RTC](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/amcohen/entry/git_versus_subversion_versus_rational_team_concert_basic_commandline_syntax_reference313?lang=en)

Comment: Excellent, certainly more accurate than my answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in the [help page](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/r_scm_cli_changeset.html), there is also one workaround:
**`relocate`** a file from one change set to another.